# Code not executing after true "if" statement

Tags: java

I am working on making a bank account that holds account information.

Each account gets up to 3 free withdrawals each month, with $1 being charged for every extra transaction after the first three free. I have a conditional that deals with charging customers $3 for EVERY transaction after the 3 free ones, but it isn't working right.

```
public static double getTFee(int accountNumber) {
    if (transactionCount[accountNumber] >= 4) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

The function returns 1 for every account that has 4 or more transactions, BUT it doesn't provide the right balance in the "tester" class. I.e. if the account made 5 deposits of $1 each, it should have $3 since the last two are being charged. But my tester class doesn't deduct the $1 after the 4th transaction, returning a balance of $4 for the previous scenario. Here is my tester class:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the account number.");
            CheckingAccount.setAccountNumber(scanner.nextInt());
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (bankAccount[j] == CheckingAccount.getAccountNumber()) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount you desire to deposit.: ");
                    CheckingAccount.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(scanner.next()));
                    amount[j] = amount[j] + CheckingAccount.getAmount();
                    CheckingAccount.transaction(CheckingAccount.getAccountNumber());
                    value = CheckingAccount.checkTFee(CheckingAccount.getAccountNumber());
                    System.out.println("Your balance is: $" + (amount[j] - CheckingAccount.getTFee(value)));
                } else if (bankAccount[j] != CheckingAccount.getAccountNumber()) {

            }
```

The test class runs, so the problem is not the conditional in the tester class. It must be something with the getTFee function. Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: *Obviously* the condition *isn't* true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't be returning 1 every time you call getTFee, this code will work for you:

```
public static double getTFee(int accountNumber) {
    if (transactionCount[accountNumber] >= 4) {
        return transactionCount[accountNumber] - 3;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

To explain things, `getTFee` should return 0 if the account has done 3 transactions or less, but when the account done it 4 or more, we subtract the 3 free transactions from the total transactions and return the fee (every transaction costs 1$ so there's no need to multiply the result by 1)

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!